# ASP NET MVC 3.0 GET USER INPUT

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Whats the best way to get User Input from the view to controller. I mean specific input not like "FormCollection" someting like "object person" or "int value"  and how to refresh the page on certain interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example if your view is strongly typed with a "Person" class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside your view:

```
@model MyMVCApp.Person
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    // or Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName) .. and do this for all of the properties.
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then you'd have an action that would handle the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person model)
{
    // do stuff with model here.
}
```

MVC uses what are called [ModelBinders](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) to take that form collection and map it to a model.

To answer your second question, you can refresh a page with the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Reload after 1 minute.
setTimeout(function ()
{
    window.location.reload();
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

By writing a view model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new UserViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel model)
    {
        // Here the default model binder will automatically
        // instantiate the UserViewModel filled with the values
        // coming from the form POST
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.UserViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```